# How to deal with NPM error: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'parent')?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

This NPM error happens when used in a monorepo with NPM workspaces feature. I have a monorepo with 5 packages: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e`. I also have a package in a different repository which is not a workspace. The name of that package is `x` and it depends on package `c` and `d`.

The problem happens when I try to add package `x` as a dependency for my package `e`. Every time I try: `npm install x -w packages/e`, I get following error:

```
npm ERR! Cannot set properties of null (setting 'parent')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/harshal/.npm/_logs/2022-11-11T17_27_57_008Z-debug-0.log
```

There is absolutely nothing in the error log except the fact that the error originates in `arborist` package when resolving dependencies.

I have tried using multiple NPM versions `^8.x.x` but it doesn't seem to resolve it.

Comment: Try to delete the node_modules folder and package-lock.json and run npm install again.

Comment: @joemokenela That doesn't work. It is 100% reproducible with given setup.

Comment: Set `x` as a [`peerDependencies`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies) of `e`. Depending on your exact architecture you might need to use [`peerDependenciesMeta`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependenciesmeta) to indicate optional requirements. You haven't really provided sufficient information to help with your problem.

Comment: The package x is not part of the NPM monorepo.

Comment: FWIW deleting `package-lock.json` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @HarshalPatil Any updates on this? This seems like a bug to me. I understand why circular references between packages doesn't work, but I'm in the same situation you describe, no circular references between the actual packages.

Comment: @BrianBall So far, there is no solution. My workaround is to remove all the packages from workspaces and then add them one by one such a way that a new lock file is generated which doesn't have this problem. I experimented a lot with different setup and there is no clean solution. In my case, I directly start with `e` package and then add rest of the packages to workspaces one by one.

Comment: I was able to get this working for me, but it may not be a good universal fix. If it works for you, I can write it up as an answer. Given the example you have in your question, `e` should use a file reference for `c` and `d`. So in `e`'s package.json file, instead of  having `"c": "^x.y.z."`, it should read `"c": "file:<relative path to c>"`. If `e` doesn't have `c` and `d` as dependencies, you can probably use the `overrides` options of `package.json`

Comment: @BrianBall I don't have access to that code base anymore. But I feel your answer may work. I will have to simulate it in a different repository. The only challenge will be while publishing the packages. All the packages `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `x` are published to NPM. So when publishing the package, I will have to write a script that will modify the `file:` references back to original semver and ensure that publishing of `e` happens after `c` and `d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the circular dependency - monorepo depends on external package that depends back on the monorepo.  When trying to resolve it seems to set the monorepo packages as 'null' (so as to defer resolution w/o hanging) and then when it tries to resolve that package it just fails.  I don't have a workaround, trying to figure that out for myself.

Comment: Your are probably right. But have you found anything yet?

Comment: Well we decided that we we really *should* keep the dependency graph uni-directional (between monorepos that is)

So ... that's kind of a solution.  Also `lerna` is able to deal with this problem with bootstrap so you can use lerna if you want.  Lerna's bootstrap is on the way out though in favor of npm workspaces.

Comment: It doesn't work even when using lerna.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this happen when you're trying to run `npm i` from the wrong location.

Just double check that you are actually running at the same location your `package.json` file is located.

Answer (score 2):

This error can appear when you have messed-up `peerDependencies` version pinning referencing an old package version within the monorepo itself.

> **NOTE**: It seems there are different edge cases which may produce the same cryptic error message, this is just one of them.

Given an structure like:

```bash
.
├── ...
├── packages/
|   ├── main-thing
|   |   ├── ...
|   |   └── package.json # { version: '2.0.0' }
|   ├── peer-dependant-one
|   |   ├── ...
|   |   └── package.json # { peerDependencies: { '@myorg/main-thing': '^1.0.0' } }
|   └── peer-dependant-two
|       ├── ...
|       └── package.json # { peerDependencies: { '@myorg/main-thing': '^2.0.0' } }
├── ...
└── package.json        # { workspaces: ['packages/*'] }
```

`npm install` will fail due to `@myorg/peer-dependant-one` being imposible to reference the `@myorg/main-thing@1.0.0`. The solution here is updating it to properly reference `@myorg/main-thing@2.0.0`

Comment: I exactly tried this; ensured that entire dependency chain uses exact same version of the package but it still does not work.

Comment: @HarshalPatil could you add details about your workspace tree? I may help

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this the exact error and it is thrown by arborist because that package walks up and down the tree.

In general the error is thrown when any of the dependencies cannot be resolved (mistyped or mis-resolved in the package-lock.json)

In my case, I am using [npm workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces/), I had a package which I named 'react'. I also had a dependency on React.js. This was a conflict in resolution within the package-lock.json, since node_modules/react was resolving to my package instead of React.js package.

This error can be hard to debug, but this is what I did:

1. First find out installation of which exact package is throwing this error.
2. Search package-lock.json file for this package name and check if the resolved dependency is correct.
3. If not, remove the dependency. If it is a 3-party direct dependency, you might need to replace it. If you own the dependency (local npm package) you can try to rename it.
4. If you cannot figure out which dependency is problematic, you can try removing all deps, `npm i` to clean package-lock.json and then reinstall each dependency one at a time to see which one is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me because I didn't initialize a workspace
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/workspaces#getting-started-with-workspaces

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by cleaning the npm cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` file
and run

```
npm install
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue in npm workspaces, I ended up removing the root `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again to resolve it

Answer (score -3):

I don't know why, but you can try

```
npm install npm@8.3.1 -g
or 
install node which under 16.14.0 

then
npm i -f
```

Comment: You should never use `sudo npm ...`. There is a huge attack vector behind

Comment: hey @Mikeccx is good that you try to help, but reading the previous answers it looks like it's a tree dependency issue in the packages dependencies. Forcing installation as a root user won't help, I think (and hope!)

Comment: I think that by reading the previous answers you can gather important context that help understand better the problem

Comment: @mat_jack1 That's right, `sudo` makes no sence here!